# Starting a text using By + ing form

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

Can I start a text using by + ing form? Ex. By recognizing the difficulty of the material, the teacher took extra time teaching it to her students.

Comment: Your specific example doesn't seem like a very credible ***opening*** to a text, but you could hardly argue with a book that started with, say, *By purchasing this book, you have taken the first step on a lifelong road to enlightenment*. Syntactically, I mean - you'd still be free to take issue with the *content* of the book (I probably would).

Comment: You have not chosen a very good example. There are plenty of instances where you could use *By + ing* e.g. *By helping in the shop, John was an asset to the family*. But in your sentence you do not need the *by*. I think you mean simply *Recognising the difficulty of the material, the teacher took extra time...*. The word *by* is superfluous and incorrect in that context.

Comment: What @WS2 said. In fact, although there's nothing *grammatically* wrong with ***by*** in the cited text, it makes absolutely no sense at the *semantic* level, since it appears to completely reverse ordinary notions of cause and effect.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, I agree. That puts it rather better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. This is a valid construction. Some people might protest that it sounds "business-y" and vapid if overused, however there is nothing inherently wrong with it. In fact, I argue that in conversation it is a useful mechanism to prevent monotony in sentence structure.

However, the sentence you provided doesn't quite make sense. Try reorganizing it: "The teacher took extra time teaching it to her students by recognizing the difficulty of the material". This is obviously incorrect, so moving the 'by' clause to the beginning doesn't help.

You probably mean to say "Because the material was so difficult, the teacher took extra time teaching it to her students."

Comment: Reordering the sentence doesn't help. It still doesn't make sense. It would be better without 'by', i.e.  Recognizing the difficulty of the material, the teacher took extra time teaching it to her students.

Comment: Hi Borges, This sentence was taken from the Michigan Test 2012. The key is telling me that the answer should be "Recognizing" instead of "By recognizing". I was wondering if there was a difference between both forms. Thank you.

Comment: I think WS2 is correct. The word by is superfluous and incorrect in that context.

Comment: Ahhhhh, Claudia, I see. Eliminating the 'by' would turn the original sentence into a grammatical one.  I was approaching your question from a different angle, but hopefully some of that info was helpful.

Comment: Further to chasly, the impetus for considering the reordered sentence was to emphasize the disorder, not to somehow correct it.